# htaccess redirect to a separate folder

Tags: .htaccess, centos, virtualhost

Server is CentoS 7 with Apache

I have 2 folder under var/www/html/ which are

- app/app_name/public (which contain laravel 4.2)
- landing_page (which contain a simple index.html and a create.php file for subscription)

When you are accessing

```
domain.com -- this will open the landing_page/index.html
```

I would like to make it that when domain.com/beta is open, it will open up the request to the laravel application like:

```
var/www/html/app/app_name/public
```

I have tried virtual host which is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/landing_page
ErrorLog /var/www/html/landing_page/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/landing_page/requests.log combined

Redirect /beta http://domain.com/app/app_name/public
</VirtualHost>
```

And .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Not sure what is the easiest but as long as it can make it work, should be good. Thanks.

Comment: So in the end which works? the .htaccess or the vhost setup? or none works?!

Comment: @BogdanStoica none of them works.